# Passing a hidden input value from a looped form

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

A simplified version of my code:

**html**

```
{% for c in categories %}
  <form action="" method="post">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="e" value='{{ c.id }}'>
  {{ form.submit() }}
{% endfor %}
```

**routes.py**

```
categories = Category.query.all()
form = AddAttributeForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
d = request.form.get('e')
print(d)
```

In this case, say I have 3 categories.
When I inspect the rendered html, I can clearly see the correct value of c, in each looped form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="e" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="e" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="e" value="3">
```

But when submitting the form, `e` (and therefore `d`) always give me the value `1`.

Questions here are (1) why? and (2) how to overcome this and pass the actual value of `c` to my code?

Comment: You are opening your form tag within your jinja2 loop but do not close it. It is therefore hard to be certain if you are aiming for multiple categories within a single form or multiple forms each with a single category. If you have multiple inputs with the same name within the same form then you will need to use `request.form.getlist(‘e’)` to get all the values as `request.form.get(‘e’)` will only get you th first.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the html. Not shown here, there were a few modals popping up, and they all had the same name, as it was in a loop. So, changing the modal name opened the right form.